# How to fix POST 500 (Internal Server Error) using node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm running a chatbot integrated with GPT 3.5. and when I send my text in the chatroom, the text gets posted, but I don't get a reply back. Instead in the browser console, I get:

[image: Console Browser JPG]

In the Visual Code terminal I get:
none
npm run dev

> server@1.0.0 dev
> nodemon index.js

[nodemon] 2.0.21
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
[nodemon] starting `node index.js`
Example app listening at http://localhost:1337
::1 - - [10/Mar/2023:14:13:40 +0000] "OPTIONS /openai/text HTTP/1.1" 204 0

**[...]**
**error undefined
::1 - - [10/Mar/2023:14:13:42 +0000] "POST /openai/text
HTTP/1.1" 500 47**

### **Code for Server is: **

```js
import express from "express";
import bodyParser from "body-parser";
import cors from "cors";
import dotenv from "dotenv";
import helmet from "helmet";
import morgan from "morgan";
import { Configuration, OpenAIApi } from "openai";
import openAiRoutes from "./routes/openai.js";
//import authRoutes from "./routes/auth.js";

/\* CONFIGURATIONS \*/
dotenv.config();
const app = express();
app.use(express.json());
app.use(helmet());
app.use(helmet.crossOriginResourcePolicy({ policy: "cross-origin" }));
app.use(morgan("common"));
app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: "30mb", extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ limit: "30mb", extended: true }));
app.use(cors());

/\* OPEN AI CONFIGURATION \*/
const configuration = new Configuration({
apiKey: process.env.OPEN_API_KEY,
});
export const openai = new OpenAIApi(configuration);

/\* ROUTES \*/
app.use("/openai", openAiRoutes);
//app.use("/auth", authRoutes);

/\* ERROR HANDLING \*/
app.use((err, req, res, next) =\> {
console.error(err.stack);
res.status(500).json({ error: 'Internal Server Error' });
});

/\* SERVER SETUP \*/
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 9000;
app.listen(PORT, () =\> {
console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${PORT}`);
});
```

### **ROUTES are here: **

```js
import express from "express";
import axios from "axios";
import dotenv from "dotenv";
import { openai } from "../index.js";
dotenv.config();
const router = express.Router();
router.post("/text", async (req, res) =\> {
console.log('Request:', req.body);
try {
const { text, activeChatId } = req.body;
const response = await openai.createChatCompletion({
model: "gpt-3.5-turbo",
messages: \[
{ role: "system", content: "You are a helpful assistant." },
{ role: "user", content: text },
\],
});
console.log('Response:', response);
await axios.post(
`https://api.chatengine.io/chats/${activeChatId}/messages/`,
{ text: response.data.choices\[0\].message.content },
{
headers: {
"Project-ID": process.env.PROJECT_ID,
"User-Name": process.env.BOT_USER_NAME,
"User-Secret": process.env.BOT_USER_SECRET,
},
}
);
res.status(200).json({ text: response.data.choices\[0\].message.content });
} catch (error) {
console.error("error", error.response.data.error);
res.status(500).json({ error: error.message });
}
});
router.post("/code", async (req, res) =\> {
console.log('Request:', req.body);
try {
const { text, activeChatId } = req.body;
const response = await openai.createChatCompletion({
model: "gpt-3.5-turbo",
messages: \[
{
role: "system",
content:
"You are an assistant coder who responds with only code and no explanations.",
}, // this represents the bot and what role they will assume
{ role: "user", content: text }, // the message that the user sends
\],
});
console.log('Response:', response);
await axios.post(
`https://api.chatengine.io/chats/${activeChatId}/messages/`,
{ text: response.data.choices\[0\].message.content },
{
headers: {
"Project-ID": process.env.PROJECT_ID,
"User-Name": process.env.BOT_USER_NAME,
"User-Secret": process.env.BOT_USER_SECRET,
},
}
);
res.status(200).json({ text: response.data.choices\[0\].message.content });
} catch (error) {
console.error("error", error.response.data.error);
res.status(500).json({ error: error.message });
}
});
router.post("/assist", async (req, res) =\> {
console.log('Request:', req.body);
try {
const { text } = req.body;
const response = await openai.createChatCompletion({
model: "gpt-3.5-turbo",
messages: \[
{
role: "system",
content:
"You are a helpful assistant that serves to only complete user's thoughts or sentences.",
}, // this represents the bot and what role they will assume
{ role: "user", content: `Finish my thought: ${text}` }, // the message that the user sends
\],
});
console.log('Response:', response);
res.status(200).json({ text: response.data.choices\[0\].message.content });
} catch (error) {
console.error("error", error);
res.status(500).json({ error: error.message });
}
});
export default router;\`
```

Comment: 403 means access forbidden. i think there are several setting/roles access that you need setup first.

Comment: Your code is not formatted. If you want people to read it, you probably should fix that.

Answer (score -1):

Check in the `package.json` that you are using openai version 3.2.0, since earlier versions do not support `createChatCompletion()`.